# Prononciation du verbe « parker/parquer » en français du Québec ?

Tags: prononciation, québec, origine-ou-raison, emprunts, fréquence-utilisation

Dans une [chanson](https://youtu.be/sYRp8oP0yiw?t=60) d'un groupe québécois, on trouve les paroles suivantes :

> [...] C’est si triste que des fois quand je rentre à la maison
>  Pis
> que j’**parke** mon vieux camion
>  J’vois toute l’Amérique qui
> pleure
>  Dans mon rétroviseur…

[dans *L'Amérique pleure* à 1:02, Les Cowboys fringants]

Le verbe [*parker*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parker) est une variante orthographique ou un anglicisme pour [*parquer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parquer#fr) (Wiktionnaire) ; les deux sont notées \paʁ.ke\. Par ailleurs au Québec, [*stationner*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4964) pour *garer/parquer* est courant (BDL).

Il est clair que le chanteur ne prononce pas \paʁ.ke\ mais plutôt ce que j'assimile être « à l'anglaise ». Il se trouve que je (sud-ouest du Québec, région mét.) prononce ce verbe exactement comme le chanteur. Je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse d'une coïncidence mais plutôt d'une prononciation courante dans ma région.

---

- Peut-on retranscire avec l'API la prononciation qu'on entend du chanteur pour le verbe en question et la qualifier ou l'expliquer ; s'agit-il d'un [emprunt phonétique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5444#Phon%C3%A9tiques) ?
- Cette prononciation du verbe est-elle uniforme à la grandeur du Québec ou autrement quelle est sa fréquence relative par rapport aux autres ou sa distribution géographique dans la province ou au pays ?

Comment: USITO:  garer, stationner.
Parquer sa voiture dans la rue.
« Jack faisait klaxonner le camion jaune parqué devant la porte » (V.-L. Beaulieu, 1970). https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/parquer

Comment: J'ai trouvé ceci qui traite indirectement du sujet : [_L’adaptation phonologique des emprunts à l’anglais dans les dictionnaires québécois_](https://books.openedition.org/pusl/26437) et un autre [contributeur](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58778677#58778677) a identifié dans un outil des [prononciations](https://youglish.com/pronounce/parking/french/qc?) de _parking_ plutôt à la française.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "English" pronunciation of ''r'' after a vowel in borrowings from English is the usual pronunciation in Montreal and other regions of Quebec where there has historically been a high degree of contact with English, such as the Outaouais or the Eastern Townships. In Quebec City and most of eastern Quebec it is perfectly normal to use a French ''r'' in these cases, though an English ''r'' is also possible.

In some (but by no means all) francophone communities in Canada but outside of Quebec, it is not uncommon to hear an English ''r'' in French words, particularly among younger speakers, even ones for whom French is completely dominant. On hearing this, Quebecers may erroneously assume that English is dominant for them.

Comment: Ok, very interesting and informative, indeed, for me. My point is **merely** this: in all three languages I speak, borrowings from any source  language **usually** are pronounced by native speakers of the target within the target language's sound system. Now, with French, if you listen to that song, the singer's pronunciation of park with an American accent is actually more difficult to do than keeping it within the French sound system. It requires extra effort to say park with an AmE accent than a French one. That's all. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: In the states, you will hear Spanish speakers who have a good command of English revert to the Spanish pronunciation of certain Spanish borrowings in English. That for me makes sense because their native sound system was Spanish to begin with.  Likewise, when I hear French people from France speaking English and they mention something like a place name in France, they will usually use their French accent for it and not "americanize it". When I speak French, if I use an AmE borrowing in French, I try and said it like French people do. So, I will say un mél, for email, for example.

Comment: @Lambie. Hi. Actually, it's common for languages to have sounds that are only used in loanwords. For example, in Engish, it's common to pronounce loanwords from French with the proper nasal vowels, or some approximation.This doesn't necessarily mean wholesale adoption of the French sound system, of course. French and Englsh also have a *ch* sound for Scottish or German words.  Likewise, in Canadian French, only certain English sounds are used. So, for example, you'll never hear an English "dark" *l*, and you'll only hear [a], never [æ], where English would have [æ] in a word.

Comment: It would be fair to say that the way English words are pronounced in Montreal French is much closer to English than it is in European French, but it is still quite far from English, for various reasons. Often a young Quebec anglophone will have such a good command of French that the first hint of his Englishness is that he may - intentionally or not - pronounce English words in English rather than in the specific Canadian French system for English loanwords. The effect is similar to a Hispanic American speaking unaccented English but then saying *Latino* in Spanish in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree with what you say about French loanwords in English. AmE speakers typically do not use French pronunciation, maybe some imagined approximation. I would not say: I have been to Pari. Or cul de sac, I would say: cull de sac. And if a loan word is proper noun, that's different from *a verb which is already incorporated into the dialect*. Pronunciation code switching like that strikes me as odd. I have never heard it in any other language I speak (Portuguese and Spanish).

Comment: A comparable situation comes from border towns in Mexico and the US. Mexicans have incorporated a bunch of AmE words but never use an AmE accent iin doing so. truck becomes troca, with no aspiration.  And, well, AmE speakers who speak Spanish just aspirate the hell out of everything (unless they have learned not to).

Comment: @Lambie Of course, I would say *Paris* and *cul-de-sac* exactly as you would. Some loanwords are fully anglicized, and I'd say *Paris* is arguably a native English word.. But not all loanwords are necessarily fully nativized. For example, the Merriam-Webster gives a fully anglicized pronunciation of *genre* as zhän-rə, but it also gives zhä<sup>n</sup>- as an alternative, including a nasal vowel not occuring in native English words. For *doyen* it likewise lists a pronunciation with a nasal vowel as an option, and for *en passant* this is the only one given. I could give more examples.

Comment: Anyway, the bottom line is, French Canadians do *not* pronounce English loanwords completely in English. It's just that their system of pronunciation for these words incorporates more English sounds than European French would use.

Comment: Ah, now we are getting somewhere. "French Canadians do *not* pronounce English loanwords completely in English". So, for me, in that song, that single word parqué pronounced à l'américaine just really stood out. Had the entire song had an AmE flavour, it wouldn't have.

Comment: The way the verb was pronounced here by the singer, and the way I pronounce it, don't stand out in comparison to the pronounciation of other loanwords we use, including those other in the song (**job done, yeah, container, Florida turnpike, trucker, Klondike, Interstate 95, la game**). If one considers _parke_ had a AmE flavour, then they all do and this is the way those loanwords are pronounced. The only place we're getting at is the coming to terms with this fact. The verb _parker_ was singled out because of sheer ignorance and the rest was ignored because of a single track logic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ce *R* correspond à la variante du *R* anglais décrite comme *[spirante rétroflexe voisée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_spirante_r%C3%A9troflexe_vois%C3%A9e)* [ɻ].

Elle ne semble être utilisé en français québécois que dans des emprunts à l'anglais et donc bien correspondre au lien fourni.

2. Je laisse la deuxième partie de la question avec quelqu'un de plus au fait des usages canadiens.